# Insert new DBGrid rows containing corresponding values from a TreeView as well as a Memo

Tags: delphi

I have a `TreeView` showing a *file location* and subsequent *folders* inside it:

[image]

I then have a `Memo` showing some *drive letters*:

[image]

Then I have a `DBGrid` with two fields named: `location` and `usb`

### **What I'm trying to do:**

- Get first `Node` name under the `RootNode` as well as the first `line` in the `Memo` and add them to the first `row` in the `Grid` - `Node` name under `field location` and `Memo line` under the `field usb`.
- Continue doing the same with the rest (`Node` #2 name under `RootNode` and `Memo line` #2 goes under `DBGrid row` #2 location and `row` #2 usb and so on..) until it hits the last line on the `Memo`.
- Then continue down the `TreeView Node` adding `Node` name to `field` named `location` but start from the first line in the `Memo` for its corresponding `field` named `usb`.

For the above example end result as rows in the grid would be:

```
location                usb
---------------------------
New Folder              G
New Folder - Copy       H
New Folder - Copy (10)  I
New Folder - Copy (11)  J
New Folder - Copy (12)  G
New Folder - Copy (13)  H
New Folder - Copy (14)  I
New Folder - Copy (15)  J
New Folder - Copy (2)   G
New Folder - Copy (3)   H
New Folder - Copy (4)   I
New Folder - Copy (5)   J
New Folder - Copy (6)   G
New Folder - Copy (7)   H
New Folder - Copy (8)   I
New Folder - Copy (9)   J
```

Code so far:

```
with ClientDataSet1 do
begin
for i := 0 to Memo2.Lines.Count -1 do
 begin
 Append;
 FieldByName('usb').AsString := Memo2.Lines[i];
 Post;
 end;
end;

with ClientDataSet1 do
begin
for i := 1 to TreeView1.Items.Count -1 do
 begin
 Append;
 FieldByName('location').AsString := TreeView1.Items.Item[i].Text;
 Post;
 end;
end;
```

This obviously isn't desired as it introduces separate rows - not what I'm describing above.

Then tried something like this:

```
with ClientDataSet1 do
 begin
 for i := 1 to TreeView1.Items.Count -1 do 
 for i2 := 0 to Memo2.Lines.Count -1 do
  begin
  Append;
  FieldByName('location').AsString := TreeView1.Items.Item[i].Text;
  FieldByName('usb').AsString := Memo2.Lines[i2];
  Post;
 end;
end;
```

But this obviously just adds 4 rows containing the drive letters in order but with the same Node name, for each Node. Probably a stupid way to approach it too, I've never fully understood loops, they're usually quite confusing for me.

How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, I think this should do what you want:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
  Line : Integer;

  function NextLine(Line : Integer) : Integer;
  begin
    Result := Line;
    inc(Result);
    if Result = Memo2.Lines.Count then
      Result := 0;
  end;
begin
  ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;

  Line := 0;
  for i := 0 to TreeView1.Items.Count - 1 do begin
    ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([Memo2.Lines[Line], TreeView1.Items[i].Text]);
    Line := NextLine(Line);
  end;
end;
```

As you can see, it uses a `for` loop to iterate the TreeView.Items like your code does and simultaneously cycles through the lines of Memo2.

Conceivably, you might want to do

```
ClientDataSet1.IndexFieldNames := 'USB;Location';
```

to make sure the rows are in the correct order.

Btw, imo InsertRecord is much tidier and more concise than Append, FieldByName x2, Post.

Comment: Yup, I fudged it up while pasting. Fixed now and it works perfectly. Thank you so much, always nice answers from you MartynA :) I'll use the index suggestion too and yes, InsertRecord makes it indeed much tidier. Will make a point to remember using that going forward.